# AngularJS $uibModal blur lose focus issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, blur

I'm new working with AngularJS, I'm trying to fire a blur event when a uibModal lose focus, can you please help?

i have [this code](https://plnkr.co/edit/wmXBApIRMuKqTekMPAje?p=info)

```
  <script>
  let stateCheck = setInterval(() => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    document.getElementById("MainModal").onblur = function () {
       alert("blur event");                   
    };
  }
}, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: The first thing you need to learn about Angular when asking a question on SO is that there is a difference between [angular] and [angularjs]. The difference being that the [angular] tag is for Angular 2+ questions and the [angularjs] tag is for 1.x questions. I suggest you update your tags to increase your chances of getting helpful answers.

Comment: More on topic though, why are you trying to fire a blur event anyway? Are you trying to hook into the close event of the modal? I don't believe that you can have an onblur event for the modal seeing as the modal itself isn't focused but rather the children elements of the modal.

Comment: angular 1.5 ....

Comment: really, i need to know when the Modal lose focus or is about getting closed or disposed ...

Comment: I believe it is only possible to capture the events after the modal has been closed, whether it is via a close or dismiss. Closing on focus loss counts as a dismissal. Would that be good enough or do you have to capture it before the modal is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you want to bind to the 'modal.closing' event that gets broadcast to the modal's $scope *before* the modal gets closed:

```
.controller('CamaraCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, ...) {
    $scope.$on('modal.closing', function(event, reason, closed) {
      // Do whatever you want here
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a Modal with video to take multiple photos,so, its working ok,but if i try something like below,the video tag and stream variable doesn't exist anymore and camera continue working...that is bad!

```
var instancia = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: raiz + 'ModCamara',
                controller: 'camaraController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                size: "md",
                resolve: {
                    //some data
                    }
                }
            }).closed.then(function () {
                alert("closed");// cant close the video here... video div doesnt exists
            });
```

so the best way to resolve my issue is the blur event ... but the blur event doesn't seems to be working with modal/angularJS